# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define at ... with 'grunt test' using jasmine in require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I'm a little confused. In my little project I'm using Jasmine, Require.js, Phantomjs and Grunt (all these via Yeoman). So when run I `grunt test` in the terminal, I get the error:

```
>> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define at 
>> test/spec/testSpec.js:15

Warning: No specs executed, is there a configuration error? Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

But when I perform the test in a browser, the test goes fine...

Here's my simple test spec:

```
define(['spec/test'], function(Test) {

  describe('Test for unit-test', function() {
    describe('Test namespace', function() {
      it('should be defined', function() {
        expect(Test).toBeDefined();
      });
    });
  });

});
```

Module:

```
define([], function () {
  var Test = {};

  return Test;
});
```

Can someone help me solve this, please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems Grunt doesn't load RequireJS. Maybe [this](https://github.com/jamespamplin/grunt-contrib-jasmine-requirejs-example) could help you.